# How to print spring datasource values in SpringBoot 2.0 application

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-data-jpa

I want to see all the default/set values for spring datasource. I am using SpringBoot 2.0.

Can someone please tell me know to print these values in a java applications.

Reason I am asking because I want to find whether the property I added to my application.yml is overwriting the default values

application.yml is as below

```
.
.
.
.
        spring:
          datasource:
            url: ${vcap.services.cas-db.credentials.url}
            username: ${vcap.services.cas-db.credentials.username}
            password: ${vcap.services.cas-db.credentials.password}
.
.
.
.
```

I have not mentioned parameters such as **hikari connectionTimeout** in my yml file. If want to print the values for these parameters

Comment: You can use `dataSource.toString()` to see its values.

Comment: How to get dataSource parameter to my application

Comment: It's for debugging purpose, inject it somewhere and call `toString()` or breakpoint there and evaluate its values.

Comment: Sorry, my question is on how to inject dataSource. I tried to Autowired DataSource but not working

Comment: That means you don't have a datasource bean. Where didi you inject it?

Comment: My DB parameters only in application.yml file. I connect to DB using a repository interface extends CrudRepository

Comment: Try injecting `HikariDatasource` with `@Autowired`.

Comment: Any idea how to do same in Spring boot 1.5? Hikari is not available in 1.5

Comment: See my answer for more details about your last question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spring Boot 1.5 try this datasource type : `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource` (I'm not 100% sure). If you defined your own datasource using `javax.sql.DataSource` so use this one.

Since Spring Boot 2.0, default datasource is `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource`.

Comment: I tried @Autowired org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource for SpringBoot 1.5 and I get error

BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource'

Comment: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URL must start with 'jdbc'

Comment: You misconfigured your datasource url, which always starts with `jdbc:....`

Comment: my  url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//111.111.11.100:1122/ABCD

Comment: I can successfully connect to database with these parameters

Comment: So where is the problem since you can well connect to your db. When does this exception happen?